# Python: Using ThreadPoolExecutor within a Thread

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor within a Thread with this script:

```
def worker(x):
    return x*x


def FncWithinThread():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
        futures_to_data = {executor.submit(worker, i):i for i in range(10)}
```

When you run the FncWithinThread function it shows the following error:

```
futures_to_data = {executor.submit(worker, i):i for i in range(10)}
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jhona\anaconda3\envs\Sandwich\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 169, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
```

I was trying to use other libraries but when using Requests.post it is very slow compared to ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: to me it seems like you're trying to run `futures_to_data = {executor.submit(worker, i):i for i in range(10)}` outside the `with TPE as exe:` block which obviously doesn't work since the pool is no longer alive. Also your dict should probably be the other way around: `data_to_feature = {i:executor.submit(worker, i) for i in range(10)}` although using a dict to contain features is a questionable choice all on its own

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is getting closed within a thread. You should ensure that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is properly managed and not closed prematurely. Here's an example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def worker(x):
    return x * x

def FncWithinThread():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
        # Create a list of futures
        futures = [executor.submit(worker, i) for i in range(10)]

    # You can now access the results if needed
    results = [future.result() for future in futures]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FncWithinThread()
```

Comment: The problem persists when executing executor.submit, the message RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown appears. It seems to me that this problem is due to the fact that I am previously performing a Threading.Thread and it generates some conflict.